Deploy .NET Blazor web assembly application in Azure Static WebApp - API error 404
I'm trying to deploy a .NET Blazor web assembly application in Azure Static WebApp. I followed the instructions in this document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor.
The web app is deployed and I could see the website, but the API throws a 404 - not found error.


This is my gitlab-ci.yaml file
stages:
  - deploy

variables:
  API_TOKEN: $AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN
  APP_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/ExpenseTracker.Client'
  OUTPUT_PATH: 'wwwroot'
  API_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/ExpenseTracker.Server'
  PUBLISH_DIR: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/publish'

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/static-web-apps/azure-static-web-apps-deploy
  script:
    - echo "App deployed successfully."


This is my staticwebapp.config.json file
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "route": "/api/*",
            "serve": "/api"
        }
    ],
    "navigationFallback": {
        "rewrite": "/index.html"
    }
}

ExpenseTracker.Server program.cs:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using DinkToPdf;
using DinkToPdf.Contracts;
using ExpenseTracker.Server.AppDbContext;
using ExpenseTracker.Server.Entities;
using ExpenseTracker.Server.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();  // Combine razor pages and api

// For Entity Framework
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ExpenseTrackerDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

// For DI registration
builder.Services.AddTransient<IExpenseTrackerService, ExpenseTrackerService>();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles(); // to laod wasm static files

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles(); //  a special middleware component to serve the client 

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages(); // Combine razor pages and api

app.MapControllers();// handle /api

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");  // handle  everything else

app.Run();

ExpenseTracker.Client program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using ExpenseTracker.Client;
using MudBlazor.Services;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddMudServices();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

await builder.Build().RunAsync();

Why does the API return a 404 error while the web app URL is functioning fine?

If possible, share your github repo?

Hi, https://gitlab.com/Thanusiga/expense-tracker/

Are you using local database or Azure database after deployment?

I haven't configured the Azure database yet. I am still using local db. The API endpoint throws 404 - not found error. if there is any exception because of DB it the error code will be 500 noh?

Is your Client working locally?

The client is working locally. but API is not running in the same base url
.

The client is working locally. but API is not running in the same base URL. https://localhost:7093/api/invoice?perPage=10&page=1&SortBy= returns a html output - `200 OK (from disk cache).

Client is running at 7093, Server is running at 5002 Is this correct?

Yes. How can I know in which port Api is running in Azure?
I want to mention this, if I run the Server project (API), then both Client and Api are running in 5002 locally

Did you deploy both client and server app to one static web app?

yes I followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor

As per this Document if you use your own api, First you need to host it in Azure app server or Azure function or API management or Container apps.

For your case you need use Bring your own APIs method but your using Managed APIs method, it is only for Azure Functions.

So can't we deploy both Server Client of a .NET Web Assembly both in Azure Static web app?

As I mentioned in Comments, as per this document if you use your own Api it would be hosted in Azure Function, Azure Web App, Api Management or Containers apps.
I edited your code to deploy Api to azure app service.
I added below lines to the program.cs file and comment the lines which is linked to the blazor web app.
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{
    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; 
    else
        x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    }
);

Below is the complete Program.cs file:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using DinkToPdf;
using DinkToPdf.Contracts;
using ExpenseTracker.Server.AppDbContext;
using ExpenseTracker.Server.Entities;
using ExpenseTracker.Server.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowBlazorClient",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("*")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ExpenseTrackerDbContext>(options =>
{    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddTransient<IExpenseTrackerService, ExpenseTrackerService>();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{
    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; 
    else
        x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;  
}
);
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("AllowBlazorClient");
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); 
app.Run();

After Successfully deployed to the azure web app I got below output:
Azure App Service:


I added below azure web app uri  to the Blazor client app Program.cs file.
https://<AzureWebAppName>.azurewebsites.net
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using ExpenseTracker.Client;
using MudBlazor.Services;
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddMudServices();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://kaexpensetrackerserver.azurewebsites.net") });
await builder.Build().RunAsync();

I enable the Cors in the Api by placing static web api uri in the Allowed Origins as shown below.

Below is the Azure Static web app output:


@hanushi Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

Hi, @Aslesha Sorry for the delay. thanks for your effort. I'll check and let you know
